# Optimise Custom Wordpress SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, wordpress

I have a wordpress website whereby I am doing an ajax request to return a json object of property details (to use with google maps). I currently have the following query:

```
SELECT
p.ID AS 'id',
p.post_title AS 'title',
t.name AS 'property_type',
c.name AS 'listing_type',
pm.meta_value AS 'address',
pm2.meta_value AS 'latitude',
pm3.meta_value AS 'longitude',
pm4.meta_value AS 'price',
pm5.meta_value AS 'bedrooms',
pm6.meta_value AS 'baths',
pm7.meta_value AS 'show_date',
p.guid,
wm2.meta_value AS 'image'
FROM
wp_posts p
    INNER JOIN
wp_postmeta AS pm ON pm.post_id = p.ID
    INNER JOIN
wp_postmeta AS pm2 ON pm2.post_id = p.ID
    INNER JOIN
wp_postmeta AS pm3 ON pm3.post_id = p.ID
    INNER JOIN
wp_postmeta AS pm4 ON pm4.post_id = p.ID
    INNER JOIN
wp_postmeta AS pm5 ON pm5.post_id = p.ID
    INNER JOIN
wp_postmeta AS pm6 ON pm6.post_id = p.ID
INNER JOIN
wp_postmeta AS pm7 ON pm7.post_id = p.ID
    LEFT JOIN
wp_term_relationships AS r ON (p.ID = r.object_id)
    INNER JOIN
wp_term_taxonomy AS x ON (r.term_taxonomy_id = x.term_taxonomy_id)
    INNER JOIN
wp_terms AS t ON (r.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id)
    LEFT JOIN
wp_term_relationships AS v ON (p.ID = v.object_id)
    INNER JOIN
wp_term_taxonomy AS z ON (v.term_taxonomy_id = z.term_taxonomy_id)
    INNER JOIN
wp_terms AS c ON (v.term_taxonomy_id = c.term_id)
    LEFT JOIN
wp_postmeta wm1 ON (wm1.post_id = p.id
    AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL
    AND wm1.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id')
    LEFT JOIN
wp_postmeta wm2 ON (wm1.meta_value = wm2.post_id
    AND wm2.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
    AND wm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL)
WHERE
pm.meta_key = 'property_address'
    AND pm2.meta_key = 'property_lat'
    AND pm3.meta_key = 'property_lng'
    AND pm4.meta_key = 'property_price'
    AND pm5.meta_key = 'property_beds'
    AND pm6.meta_key = 'property_baths'
    AND pm7.meta_key = 'property_show_date'
    AND x.taxonomy = 'property-type'
    AND z.taxonomy = 'listing-type'
    AND p.post_type = 'property'
    AND p.post_status = 'publish'
```

which returns the data perfectly:

id | title | property_type | listing_type | address | latitude | longitude | price | bedrooms | baths | show_date | guid

however, as soon as I have more than one property on the website the query seems to struggle and even breaks the database (Completely lost the ability to connect to db taking the website down, having to start again with a new db). I have pinned the problem down to the taxonomy part of my query:

```
LEFT JOIN
wp_term_relationships AS r ON (p.ID = r.object_id)
    INNER JOIN
wp_term_taxonomy AS x ON (r.term_taxonomy_id = x.term_taxonomy_id)
    INNER JOIN
wp_terms AS t ON (r.term_taxonomy_id = t.term_id)
    LEFT JOIN
wp_term_relationships AS v ON (p.ID = v.object_id)
    INNER JOIN
wp_term_taxonomy AS z ON (v.term_taxonomy_id = z.term_taxonomy_id)
    INNER JOIN
wp_terms AS c ON (v.term_taxonomy_id = c.term_id)
```

but I have no idea how to improve on this. 
Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the meaning of *breaks the database*? Please [edit] your question. Does the query never finish? Does the database server software crash? Is your data corrupted?

Comment: Run an `EXPLAIN` onto such a query to see whether you need some more indices

Comment: `I have pinned the problem down to the taxonomy part of my query` - Would you mind sharing that information? You can help us help you , you know ^^

Comment: I have edited my question to try clarify. I'm a noob when it comes to sql so the EXPLAIN command is a bit foreign to me. Essentially l would like to know if my query can be improved in any way; performance wise or simplified

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT
id,
post_title,
guid,
pm.meta_value AS 'address',
pm2.meta_value AS 'latitude',
pm3.meta_value AS 'longitude',
pm4.meta_value AS 'price',
pm5.meta_value AS 'bedrooms',
pm6.meta_value AS 'baths',
pm7.meta_value AS 'show_date',
wm2.meta_value AS 'image',
(SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(wp_terms.name
                SEPARATOR ', ')
    FROM
        wp_terms
            INNER JOIN
        wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
            INNER JOIN
        wp_term_relationships wpr ON wpr.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
    WHERE
        taxonomy = 'property-type'
            AND wp_posts.ID = wpr.object_id) AS 'property_type',
(SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(wp_terms.name
                SEPARATOR ', ')
    FROM
        wp_terms
            INNER JOIN
        wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
            INNER JOIN
        wp_term_relationships wpr ON wpr.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
    WHERE
        taxonomy = 'listing-type'
            AND wp_posts.ID = wpr.object_id) AS 'listing_type'
FROM
wp_posts
    INNER JOIN
wp_postmeta AS pm ON pm.post_id = wp_posts.ID
    INNER JOIN
wp_postmeta AS pm2 ON pm2.post_id = wp_posts.ID
    INNER JOIN
wp_postmeta AS pm3 ON pm3.post_id = wp_posts.ID
    INNER JOIN
wp_postmeta AS pm4 ON pm4.post_id = wp_posts.ID
    INNER JOIN
wp_postmeta AS pm5 ON pm5.post_id = wp_posts.ID
    INNER JOIN
wp_postmeta AS pm6 ON pm6.post_id = wp_posts.ID
    INNER JOIN
wp_postmeta AS pm7 ON pm7.post_id = wp_posts.ID
    INNER JOIN
wp_postmeta wm1 ON (wm1.post_id = wp_posts.id
    AND wm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL
    AND wm1.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id')
    INNER JOIN
wp_postmeta wm2 ON (wm1.meta_value = wm2.post_id
    AND wm2.meta_key = '_wp_attached_file'
    AND wm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL)
WHERE
post_type = 'property'
    AND pm.meta_key = 'property_address'
    AND pm2.meta_key = 'property_lat'
    AND pm3.meta_key = 'property_lng'
    AND pm4.meta_key = 'property_price'
    AND pm5.meta_key = 'property_beds'
    AND pm6.meta_key = 'property_baths'
    AND pm7.meta_key = 'property_show_date'";
```